# How can I resolve machine key problem or use some other method?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

Our IT partner has two servers where we have deployed our application (IIS). They have set up a load balancer and sticky sessions, using NetScaler, and it is working correctly. What we want to achieve is that if a user is logged in on server B and we shut down that server, they must continue with the application as if nothing happened. Right now, they get logged out after we shut down one server. We tried putting a machine key in the web config on both servers, but that didn't work. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I think [Distributed SQL Server Cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-7.0#distributed-sql-server-cache) could be a best choice for you.